# Why does "quser" always say "none" for "IDLE TIME"?

Tags: windows-10

I was told to use the "quser" command to determine how long the user has been idle, but it always says "none".

I set up a script to run it every 3 seconds, without me typing anything or moving the mouse. It never changes from "none". Even if I enter the lock screen and wait for many seconds, when I log back in, the script just has outputted "none" for every query for the "IDLE TIME" column.

"quser /?" outputs zero information, as usual, so the manual doesn't help me one bit. Not a word about what "idle time" means, nor what format it will be in. And it's always "none".

What?

Comment: As you are not on Windows Server, then this command is only partially functional.

Comment: @harrymc on my Windows 10 Pro, running quser from the command prompt says I'm idle for 14:23 My pc is domain joined though, so maybe that's why it does work on my pc.

Comment: C:\Users\LPChip.NEBULA>quser
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>lpchip                console            25  Active      14:26  15-4-2020 11:26

Comment: @LPChip: Windows 10 Enterprise, quser gave since always IDLE TIME of "none".

Comment: @LPChip: Now tested on Windows Server 2008 & 2016 and even Windows 7. IDLE TIME is always "none".

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft describes
[query user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user)
as:

> Displays information about user sessions on a Remote Desktop Session Host (rd Session Host) server.

Website SS64 describes
[Query User / QUSER](https://ss64.com/nt/query-user.html)
more precisely as:

> Display information about user sessions on a Terminal server or a Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server.

My conclusion is that this command only fully works for remote user sessions.
When invoked in a local login session, it just gives a partial result.

Tested on : Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 & 2016, Windows 10 Enterprise.
Result is always "none".

Comment: I did some of my own testing.  I've seen it change to 7 (seconds) and 3 (seconds) while I was absolutely not moving mouse or using keyboard for more than 300 seconds.  I even used /SERVER to monitor a disconnected user and that never went idle.  IDLE is a lie.

Comment: @user922020: Windows 11 Pro - IDLE TIME is always "none".